# Why it's not possible to chain ref returns if the inner method also accepts out params in C#7?

Tags: c#, ref, c#-7.0

I was experimenting with the new C#7 features and I found something strange. 
Given the following simplified scenario:

```
public struct Command
{
}

public class CommandBuffer
{
    private Command[] commands = new Command[1024];
    private int count;

    public ref Command GetNextCommand()
    {
        return ref commands[count++];
    }

    public ref Command GetNextCommand(out int index)
    {
        index = count++;
        return ref commands[index];
    }
}

public class BufferWrapper
{
    private CommandBuffer cb = new CommandBuffer();

    // this compiles fine
    public ref Command CreateCommand()
    {
        ref Command cmd = ref cb.GetNextCommand();
        return ref cmd;
    }

    // doesn't compile
    public ref Command CreateCommandWithIndex()
    {
        ref Command cmd = ref cb.GetNextCommand(out int index);
        return ref cmd;
    }
}
```

Why does the second method give me the following compiler error?

```
CS8157  Cannot return 'cmd' by reference because it was initialized to a value that cannot be returned by reference
```

I know the compiler can't allow you to return a ref to a var that could end up being dead later on, but I don't really see how having an additional out param changes this scenario in any way.

Comment: It is a generic compiler problem called "pointer aliasing".  The kind of problem that the optimizer in a C or C++ compiler must solve and tends to flub.  Basic issue is that the `out` argument permits an observable side-effect that can invalidate the reference.  Proving that such as assignment doesn't invalidate cmd is very hard to do.  And it in fact does, cmd no longer references commands[index].  You'll say "no problem" in this case, the C# compiler says "not so sure, let's not".  Otherwise the basic reasons why Fortran is still relevant and why it took a long time for ref to get added.

Comment: Gotcha. So basically there are scenarios where having an out parameter could invalidate the reference later on so the compiler makes all such methods illegal instead of trying to analyse them because it's not really a reliable process.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call ref return method that has ref or out param

this change can be fix it

```
public ref Command CreateCommandWithIndex(out int index)
        {
            ref Command cmd = ref cb.GetNextCommand(out index);
            return ref cmd;
        }
```

then when you call this method call it by value