# Why cannot return a nested ref return result if the inner method has another ref/out parameter?

Tags: c#, ref

I thought I understood [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) of ref returns as well as escaping scopes.

But now I found a case and I don't get why is it illegal. It seems that ref return cannot be used if the value to return comes from a nested method with any ref/out arguments.

```
public static ref T RefReturn<T>()
{
    ref T result = ref GetResult<T>(normalParam: default); // compiles
    // ref T result = ref GetResult<T>(out bool outParam); // CS8157 at the return statement
    // ref T result = ref GetResult<T>(boxedParam: new StrongBox<bool>()); // a suboptimal workaround

    // ... code

    return ref result;
}

// the bodies below are just dummy examples
private static ref T GetResult<T>(bool normalParam) => ref (new T[1])[0];

// note that this method compiles in itself but unlike in case of the the previous method
// it is illegal to return its result again
private static ref T GetResult<T>(out bool outParam)
{
    outParam = true;
    return ref (new T[1])[0];
}

// though a ref/out parameter does not work we can mimic something similar without
// making it impossible to return its result from a caller
private static ref T GetResult<T>(StrongBox<bool> boxedParam)
{
    boxedParam.Value = true;
    return ref (new T[1])[0];
}
```

I can live with the workaround but I don't understand how an independent by-ref argument makes this solution harmful. AFAIK they must not be dangerous to the inner ref result; otherwise, the inner method itself should trigger some error, too. Or am I wrong? What do I miss?

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iH3C3t) is the live example of the code sample above.

Comment: Discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45929614/4137916) (the top comment should have been the answer). An `out bool` parameter is not the same thing as an `out bool` local; the compiler can prove use of the former safe, but not the latter (or rather it won't even try).

Comment: Before answering the question it will help to clarify where exactly your understanding is on these issues. Consider this simpler case: `static ref int M() { int x = 0; ref int y = ref N(ref x); return ref y;} static ref int N(ref int z) { return ref z; }`  (1) Is it clear to you why that must be illegal? If not, get that clear in your mind first. (2) given that this must be illegal, where in your opinion should the compiler report the error and why?

Comment: @EricLippert: Oooh, I think it's clear now. And you helped me to understand why the workaround in the linked post works (though I don't really like it either): bubbling the out parameter up to the same level as the ref return value makes the error go away: `ref T RefReturn<T>(out bool outParam)`. Create an answer if you wish and I will accept it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thank you for your finding. It took some time for me to understand both the comment and why the posted 'fix' works but Eric gave me the last piece of missing information.

Comment: This feature was actually designed and implemented in a prototype at least twice (once by me) many years before it made it into the shipped version of C#. During that design process we kicked around a lot of possible rules for detecting when this sort of situation could be "known to be safe"; there are times when the compiler can prove it is impossible for the returned ref to be an alias to the passed-in ref. Should we suppress the error in those cases? Could we make the verifier happy in those cases? And could we explain the rules in the spec?

Comment: Design is the process of resolving conflicts, and there is a big conflict here between making the rule simple, implementable and understandable, and making the rule NOT disallow safe programs. The team eventually arrived at the decision to lean towards "make it simple", so there are cases where you know the program is safe, and I know it is safe, but neither the compiler nor the verifier know that and so it is disallowed. That then causes user confusion of its own. It's a tricky problem.

Comment: In any event: glad you got it figured out, happy to help!